# Does MySQL have an aggregate ST_UNION()?

Tags: mysql, gis

I'm struggling for hours to get my query work but with no success.

I have a table with a GEOMETRY column which stores the POLYGON of a given area from sub-localities.
Now i want to Union them all to one higher level boundary of the parent area for example:

```
SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM area
```

I always the the error:

> #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ST_Union'

I don't think that this is the wanted behaviour of the function, since this makes it completely worthless. Does anybody know how to use this function to generate the intended results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have an aggregate form of `ST_Union`, or any other spatial function.

- [docs on `ST_Union(g1, g2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-union)

If you're looking for spatial aggregates you'll have to migrate to PostgreSQL/PostGIS. MySQL has only minimal GIS functionality.

```
SELECT ST_Union( Point(0,0), Point(0,1) );
```

For a comparison of MySQL and PostgreSQL, see my post here

- [PostgreSQL vs. MySQL: spatial feature comparison](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191336/2639)

Comment: Thanks, i should have read the docs more thoroughly, thought that the ST_UNION() function would really aggregate, instead it just concatenates values.

Comment: @Daniel if you're content with the answer, please mark it as chosen.

Comment: @Daniel st_union() does not concatenate points, it performs a union operation (but only on two input geometries). Example:
```SET @poly1 = Polygon(LineString(Point(0, 0), Point(2, 0), Point(2, 2), Point(0, 2), Point(0, 0))); 
SET @poly2 = Polygon(LineString(Point(1, 1), Point(3, 1), Point(3, 3), Point(1, 3), Point(1, 1))); 
select st_asText(st_union(@poly1, @poly2));```

Comment: @driu you can always work those kinds of clarifications into the text. I'll update with that.

Answer (score 2):

Because MySQL ST_Union() only accepts two geometries, the workaround is to construct two geometry collections. One collection contains all features to be aggregated together. It is constructed using GROUP_CONCAT() on the feature WKT. The second geometry can be an empty collection with no features.

You will likely need to substantially increase the @@sort_buffer_size and @@group_concat_max_len variables for this to work.

```
SELECT ST_Union(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      concat("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ("
             , GROUP_CONCAT( ST_AsText(shape) )
             , ")" 
            )
    ), ST_GeomFromText("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY") 
  ) as geom
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...;
```

Comment: MariaDB 10.4 works with a small difference: it doesn't supports ```GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY``` for none of the geometries. So you have to use the workaround with MariaDB 10.4 as the following: ```SELECT ST_Union( ST_GeomFromText( concat("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (", GROUP_CONCAT( ST_AsText(shape) ), ")" ) ), ST_GeomFromText("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (", GROUP_CONCAT( ST_AsText(shape) ), ")" ) ) as geom FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...;```

Answer (score 2):

I also needed this functionallity, and since MariaDB supports user defined aggregate functions, I just wrote it myself:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` AGGREGATE FUNCTION `my_gis_db`.`union_polygons`(shape GEOMETRY) RETURNS GEOMETRY
BEGIN
    DECLARE aggregated_shape GEOMETRY DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN ST_INTERSECTION(ST_ENVELOPE(aggregated_shape), aggregated_shape);

    LOOP
        FETCH GROUP NEXT ROW;
        IF shape IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF aggregated_shape IS NULL THEN
                SET aggregated_shape := shape;
            ELSE
                SET aggregated_shape := ST_UNION(aggregated_shape, shape);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END
```

After I combined the shapes of all rows, I made an intersection of itself and it's bounding box, to only get the outer shape. You can leave that part if it it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a drop in function replacement, but can get you an aggregated st_union:

```
# initialize variables:
SET @b = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY');
SET @row = 0;

SELECT ST_ASTEXT(agg) final_st_union
FROM (
  SELECT @b := ST_UNION(@b, shape) AS agg, @row := @row + 1 rownum
  FROM ..
  WHERE
) sub ORDER BY sub.rownum DESC LIMIT 1
```